# How can accept and reject order in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to accept and reject the order. If order will accept it show be saved in db, if order is rejected it show be del, but i am trying but nothing happened

View.py

```
class OrderDecision_View(TemplateView):

    template_name = "purchase/allOrders.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        allOrders = Order.objects.all()
        args = {"allOrders": allOrders}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        orderId = self.request.GET.get("order_id")
        statusAccept = self.request.GET.get("acceptButton")
        statusReject = self.request.GET.get("rejectButton")

        if statusAccept:
            try:
                orderDecision = OrderRequest(
                    order_id=orderId,
                    order_status=statusAccept,
                )
                orderDecision.save()
                return redirect("orderDecision")
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse("failed{}".format(e))

        if statusReject:
            remove = Order.objects.get(pk=statusReject.id)
            delete(remove)
```

Template

```
 {% block content %}
    {% for allorder in allOrders %}
    {{ allorder.id }}

    {{ allorder.orderProduct.product.name }}
    {{ allorder.orderProduct.quantity }}
    <button type="submit" name="acceptButton" value="accept"><a href="{% url 'orderDecision' %}?order_id={{ allorder.id }}">Accept</a></button>
    <button type="submit" name="rejectButton" value="reject"><a href="{% url 'orderDecision'%}?order_id={{ allorder.id }}"> Reject</a></button>
 {% endfor %}
{% endblock % }
```

Comment: Please post your code with proper indentation.

Comment: i update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping a link into a button doesn't do anything very sensible.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'orderDecision' %}?order_id={{ allorder.id }}">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" name="action" value="accept">Accept</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="reject">Reject</button>
</form>
```

is probably closer to what you want, with

```
statusAccept = self.request.POST.get("action") == "accept"
statusReject = self.request.POST.get("action") == "reject"
```

in the Python code.

You might want to look into doing this with an `UpdateView`, though, to save you some trouble with retrieving those order objects.

Comment: You might want `Order.objects.get(pk=orderId).delete()` there.

Comment: You'll need an `annotate(Count('orderrequest_set')).filter(orderrequest_set_count=0)` sort of addition to the queryset, but that's a different question unto itself.

Comment: So i post separate question for this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67025524/how-can-exclude-the-item-which-is-in-db-django

Comment: I post the question please answer it