# How can exclude the item which is in db Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have two issue

1. I just want to exclude the items which is in db, other item which is not in ordeerRequest table will be display, but after my query it show nothing
2. In template when i select any category it just show the last category which i added. After select any category it should show the that category but it show last added category by default

View.py

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = self.request.GET.get('action') == 'accept'
        orderCheck = Order.objects.exclude(
              orderrequest__order_status__in=OrderRequest.objects.filter(order_status=status)
        )
        args = {'orderCheck': orderCheck}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

category show

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        categories = Category.objects.all()

        categoryId = self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory')

        products = Product.objects.filter(category_id=categoryId)

        args = {'categories': categories, 'products': products, 'selectedCategory': categoryId}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Template

```
  <label>
     
        <select name="SelectCategory" >
        <option disabled="disabled" {{ selectedCategory|yesno:"yeah, no" }}> Select Category</option>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.id }}" {% if category.id == selectedCategory %} selected{% endif %} >
                {{ category.name }}
            </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
  
 </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you overcomplicated it a bit and just want:

```py
Order.objects.exclude(orderrequest__order_status=status)
```

Right now you're trying to exclude `Order` records where `Order.orderrequest.order_status` is in a `QuerySet` of `OrderRequest` objects, which it never will be, so nothing is being excluded.

As to the second part of your question, I recognize this from an earlier question you posted. You've still included `selected` in all of your `<option>` tags. If the word `selected` is in there at all, the item will be treated as `selected`, even if it says `selected="please God no"`. The proper way to mark an `<option>` as selected is:

`<option value="some_value" selected>`

Comment: I change my template code but now it always show the first product in category always even after select the any other it show the first one

Comment: I guess I still don't understand. Can you post the rendered HTML (not your template code), please?